Type Mismatch error in VBA when db.OpenRecordset("table_name")
Returns this error message
When it hits db.OpenRecordset() below in my VBA application (MS Access), it returns above 'Type mismatch' error.
Dim db As Database
Dim rst As Recordset

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Set db = CurrentDb

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tblUsageLog")

Any ideas about the reason behind this and how to fix it?
I have verified the table name 'tblUsageLog' and tried creating a new table as well. Nothing worked.

Perhaps you have ADO referenced. If so, you probably need to be more specific:
Dim db  As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Set db = CurrentDb

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tblUsageLog")

